# jenkins ssh AgentForwarding

Tags: ssh, jenkins, rsa, ssh-agent

jenkins@jenkins-server --- authenticates (w/ RSA key) ---> git@gitlab-server

jenkins@jenkins-server --- authenticates (w/ RSA key) ---> user@qa-server

From command line the output is as expected

```
jenkins@jenkins-server $ ssh user@qa-server 'ssh -T git@gitlab-server'
Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
```

Running exactly the same command from a jenkins job as "Execute Shell" build step, the output is the same (as expected).

When using a "Send files or execute commands over SSH" build step, jenkins is able to connect to `user@qa-server` but then, the `ssh -T git@gitlab-server` remote command fails with

> Permission denied, please try again.
>
> Permission denied, please try
>
> again. Permission denied (publickey,password).

It looks like that the `ssh-agent` is not running on the `qa-server` in this particular case.

All servers are running Ubuntu server.
I have jenkins [SSH Agent Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin) installed and configured.

How to debug this (and/or fix).
How can I see the exact command that jenkins is running?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow or by mistake (I'm not sure) the ssh-agent was running on `qa-server` (started on .bash_profile to load the available keys).

As soon as I stopped the ssh-agent running at `qa-server` everything started running smooth.

Recap: `ssh-agent` is running at `jenkins-server` started by jenkins SSH Agent 
and there's no `ssh-agent` running at `qa-server`.